# apt target error after re-adding vs code repo

Tags: apt, package-management

I currently experience conflicts via apt conflict messages after the additon of the `vs-code` stable repo. I suspect that I may 'double' added the repo to my system which is causing this issue.

How can I resolve this conflict? Here's the output after running `sudo apt update`:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
```

Output when I `cat` my sources list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable
main
```

and

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
```

remove on of them.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
```

Comment: They are now called /et/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft*